# Alienation of the self in Hamlet

Tags: hamlet, franz-kafka

I have been reading Harold's Bloom's literary themes on Alienation. He begins with the puzzling statement **"The supreme literary portrait of alienation is Hamlet". Now, what did he mean by that?** I'm particularly interested in this statement regarding *alienation of the self*

All I can identify is that Hamlet's values (authenticity) don't fit the values of the world (incest, duplicity) around him. Consequently, in order to mask this realisation that he doesn't fit, Hamlet alienates himself - that is, he gives up the importance of being true to oneself and honesty (shown by him pretending to be mad), and tangles himself up in a struggle between doing and not doing.

But surely, there are much better representations of alienation.

**A further question of interest: don't you think there are parallels between Gregor Samsa and Hamlet's identity crisis?**
Samsa's crisis, however, seems provoked by the external world whereas Hamlet's crisis originates from himself. Most interesting, however, is that out of this identity crisis, both of them realise how absurd their life is - I mean, Samsa and Hamlet's suffering is quite circumstantial.

Comment: Please ask for *either* why Bloom said that *or* for a comparison between Samsa and Hamlet. Those are two separate questions so answers should be able to focus on just one without worrying that they're not answering the full text. You can [edit] this question to remove one sub-question, then ask a new question with the other sub-question. Finally, please tag for both author and work: see [the tagging guide](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1618/how-do-i-tag-questions-properly)